# Does Azure SDK V12 have a SQL Db management client?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net, azure-management

I am upgrading to Azure SDK V12.

In the following [Package List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/packages) under "Libraries using Azure.Core" I find:

- [Resource Management - Resources](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/1.0.0-preview.2)
- [Resource Management - Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/1.0.0-preview.2)
- [Resource Management - Cosmos DB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB/1.0.0-preview.1)

But as yet have found a client to manage SQL Server Dbs other than the following:

- [Management - SQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/1.48.0-preview)
- [Management - SQL Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent/1.37.0)

These last 2 are `Microsoft.Management*` namespaces which *I believe* means they are not V12.  The code I am updating is using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent` presently.

Comment: Is that you want to know if the package `Azure.ResourceManager.Sql` exists?

Comment: If so, Microsoft does not publish the package. For more details, please refer to https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/mgmt/dotnet.html

Comment: @JimXu - Does `Azure.ResourceManager.Sql` exist(anywhere)?  I do not see it in the referenced link under Management, nor All.  In the referenced link, there are no Sql related Management libraries that I find.  Thus my question, Does Azure SDK V12 have a SQL Db management client?

Comment: Azure SDK V12 does not  have a SQL Db management client

Comment: @JimXu - Thank you.  This is relevant as I have already updated BlobStorage (for ex) to V12, however when I export a Db to BlobStorage, I need to use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent`'s `IStorageAccount`.  So I find I am restoring code I just removed / updated for the needs of SQL Db management.  Specifically, `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent` ultimately needs `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` which pulls in a very long list of older `Microsoft.Azure.Management.*`.  If I knew this before I started I would not have invested the time to update to V12 elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? if you have no, do you mind if I summarize the comment as an answer?

Comment: One of the ‘Microsoft.Azure.Management’ is marked pre-release, implying its actively being developed.  An answer of your comment would be useful to others.  Any info you have about the future of Azure Sdk as regards to including Management of SQL Dbs would be very appreciated.   Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize the comments as a solution

Now, If you want to manage Azure SQL resource with Azure management sdk, we just can the package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql`. The new management SDK based on `Azure. Cores` Azure.ResourceManager.Sql does not publish. Microsoft is developing it. If you want to check the update, you can visit the [page](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/mgmt/dotnet.html).